# Read input from line in J

Tags: input, j

I am very new to J (learning it for fun) and I am trying to read data from keyboard. I have tried to make a tiny script which reads in a string and reverses it:

```
|.(1!:1 3)
```

When I run it, I get a rank error. (I'm using 1!:1 3 instead of defining a verb because codegolf...)
Is there a command that can check the rank of 1!:1 3?

Comment: As @MPelletier noted, the rank error is due to erroneous parenthesization but for future reference, use [basic: `u b. 0`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dbdotu.htm) to check the rank of a verb: `(1!:1) b. 0` has `0 0 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common mistake with foreigns.

The [definition](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx001.htm) for foreign `1!:1` doesn't help, because it really reads:

```
1!:1 y      Read. y is a file name or a file number (produced by 1!:21); the 
result is a string of the file contents., e.g. 1!:1 <'abc.q'. The following 
values for y are also permitted:

1 read from the keyboard (does not work within a script)
3 read from standard input (stdin)
```

And so replacing `y` with `3` should work, right? Well, not quite, because what you're really giving as an argument in writing:

```
1!:1 3
```

is an array made of `1 3`. Sort of like giving it:

```
1!:(1 3)
```

when you want:

```
1!:1 (3)
```

For code golf purposes, use a right bracket:

```
1!:1]3
```